# Micro QR code Decoder Library for Android

Tags: java, android, qr-code

Is there any open source micro QR code scanner for Android? Ive been going a fair bit and I only found Google's library and Zxing both of which do not support it.

I run an e-commerce business, and we have a lot of inventory all of which has been marked by microqr codes.

We are planning on integrate these microqr codes for internal use, and let customers use our app to validate their products.

Am I going to have to build this myself?

Comment: I work with barcodes. In general, as soon as you start going away from the most common symbologies, you are better off getting funds for a proper library. You will be happier in the end.   I have good experience with [Code Corporation mobile SDK](https://codecorp.com/products/mobile-sdk) There is a scanner app available "Cortex Scan" to test it.

Comment: Any idea about the cost or pricing patterns?
We barely have enough money to sustain ourselves - I can only dream of this when we raise funds.

I found this https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/BoofCV/blob/v0.40/examples/src/main/java/boofcv/examples/fiducial/ExampleDetectMicroQrCode.java

which has Android Support, I could probably couple it with a socket, and produce what I need just using smart-phones. Most scanners with micro qr code capability seem extremely expensive.